# Python import module only works in a new terminal window

Tags: python, selenium, python-module

I'm trying to run the following python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.everlane.com/collections/mens-luxury-tees/products/mens-v-antique')

driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk
print driver.current_url

images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    print image.get_attribute('src')
```

However, every time I try to run it, I get this error:

```
    FitValet-MacBook-Pro:desktop fitvalet$ python selenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Users/fitvalet/Desktop/selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
FitValet-MacBook-Pro:desktop fitvalet$
```

But I've installed the module using `pip install selenium` and it installed fine. When I run a new terminal window, enter `python`, and then type in `from selenium import webdriver`, it imports fine. If I `exit()` python, and then re-enter and try again, the same above error happens, in that it can't import selenium. If I re-open terminal, then it works again, but only in the terminal python window. I can even type out every line of code and it prints the images fine in the terminal!

It never works if I just try to run the script on its own. Any ideas as to why this is? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WOW. I can't believe this, but my little script, which I so simply named "selenium.py", was the problem. The answer is, DON'T DO THIS! When the script said `from selenium import webdriver`, it somehow thought it was calling itself, and creating major errors.

I renamed the script to "myselenium.py" and it worked fine.